# llamar a una funcion js, desde boton referenciado en la parte javascript del codigo con evento "onclick"

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Muy buenas, necesitaria llamar a una funcion javascript desde el evento "onclick", pero desde la parte javascript tambien, referencio el boton con documentgetelementbyId y asigno directamente el evento onclick.
Pero me da error el evento, lo importante es llamar al evento desde javascript y no desde la etiqueta button de HTML.

function showHide () {
// Definir elemento

```
 let div = document.getElementById("div-servicios");
 if (!div) {
    // No existe, hay que crearlo
    div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute("id", "div-servicios");
    document.body.appendChild(div);

    var servicio1 = document.createElement("a");
    servicio1.innerHTML = "This is a paragraph.";
    servicio1.setAttribute("class","servicios");
    div.appendChild(servicio1);

    var servicio2 = document.createElement("a");
    servicio2.innerHTML = "This is a paragraph.";
    servicio2.setAttribute("class","servicios");
    div.appendChild(servicio2);

    var servicio3 = document.createElement("a");
    servicio3.innerHTML = "This is a paragraph.";
    servicio3.setAttribute("class","servicios");
    div.appendChild(servicio3);
    // Retardar para que aparezca con transición
    setTimeout(showHide, 50);
} else {
    // Mostrar u ocultar
    div.classList.toggle('activo');
}
```

}

let boton = document.getElementById("boto-servicio").onclick = showHide;

```
</SCRIPT>
<STYLE>

#div-servicios {
        height: 100%;
        background-color:#DD9933;
        color:white;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1; 
        right:-250px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        padding-top: 30px;
        transition: 1s;
        width:250px;
        transition:all 0.5s ease;
    }
    #div-servicios.activo{
        right:0;
    }
    .servicios{
        padding: 18px 18px 18px 32px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 25px;
        color: white;
        display: block;
    }
```

#boton-servicio{}

```
</STYLE>
```

Comment: Cuál es el error ?

Comment: Me pone que el evento onclick no funciona.. PD me ha faltado poner el botón con el id=botón-servicio en el HTML.. Pero igualmente me da el mismo error..

Comment: Este problema es derivado de [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/370471/mostrar-y-esconder-un-div-nav-lateral-html-desde-js-dom-al-clickear-un-mismo-ele), por favor no hagas nuevas preguntas, edita la que ya tienes agregando los nuevos requerimientos.

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo la lógica que implementas, sin embargo para que el evento sea "reconocido" por la pagina debes de agregarlo a el escuchador de eventos de JS.

Por lo que en vez de:

```
let boton = document.getElementById("boto-servicio").onclick = showHide;
```

Deberías de usar:

```
let boton = document.getElementById("boto-servicio");
boton.addEventListener('click',showHide);
```